# How to fix has_one / through association problem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a new project. My structure of data : 
-Audits
-Actions
-Reponses

A audit is composed of actions.
Each action **have one** reponse.
Each reponse is referenced to a action and a audit.

**Audit**

```
class Audit < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :entreprise
  has_many :reponse
  has_many :action, through: :reponse

  validates :numero, presence: true, uniqueness: true

end
```

**Action**

```
class Action < ApplicationRecord

  has_one :reponse
  has_many :audits, through: :reponse

  validates :numero, :titre, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :description, :kpi, :priority, :scale, :effectSocial, :effectEnvironmental, :effectFinancial, :impactCC, :impactD, :impactE, :impactRNN, presence: true

end
```

**Reponse**

```
class Reponse < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :audit
  belongs_to :action

end
```

I think I am pretty close, but when I launch `rails console`, add some data and try to add a reponse with :

`Action.first.create_reponse(etat: "fine", kpi: 2, commentaire: "")`

I got this :

````
Action Load (2.0ms)  SELECT  "actions".* FROM "actions" ORDER BY "actions"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.5ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
  Reponse Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "reponses".* FROM "reponses" WHERE "reponses"."action_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["action_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
 => #<Reponse id: nil, commentaire: "", etat: "fine", kpi: 2, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, action_id: 1, audit_id: nil> ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an object belongs_to another object, it needs that object's ID. So in your case, a Response would need an audit_id and an action_id.

When you try and create a response, it's failing because it doesn't have an audit_id. Your two options are to either add one into the line where you create the response:

```
Action.first.create_reponse(etat: "fine", kpi: 2, commentaire: "", audit_id: Audit.first.id)
```

Or to change your `belongs_to` to `belongs_to, required: false`. This will allow you to save the response without an audit ID, however given how you've laid out your data, it appears you want to enforce this relationship and go with the first option.

Comment: I didn't know I can pass directly the context object in the parameters. Thanks a lot !